# Javascript consecutive promises not being fired

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to login a website using node.js. After that I want to make an HTTP request to obtain a json with data. My code is as follows:

```
phantom.create()
.then(function (ph) {
    this.ph = ph;
    return ph.createPage();
})
.then(function (page) {
    this.page = page;
    return page.open('https://example.com');
})
.then(function (status) {

    if ( status === "success" ) {
        return this.page.evaluate(function() {
              document.querySelector("input[name='j_username']").value = 'example@example.net';
              document.querySelector("input[name='j_password']").value = 'example';
              console.log('Submitting logging...');
              document.querySelector("input[name='submit']").click();
        });
   } else {
       return null;
   }
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Logged in!");

    this.page.property('onResourceRequested', function(requestData, networkRequest) {
        //This event is fired 40 times, only one is interesting to me the one that has the text maps.json in it
        if (requestData.url.indexOf('maps.json') !== -1) {
            return {headers: requestData.headers, url: requestData.url};
        }
    });
});
.then(function (data) {
    //This then block is only fired once, with the first call of the first url in previous then block and data is null
    if (data) {
        // This code block is never fired because this then is only called once with data=null
        console.log(data);

        request.get({
                uri: data.url,
                headers: data.headers
        }, function(err, res, body){
          if (!err) {
                callback(null, res.headers);
          } else  {
                  console.log("Error getting data from URL: "+ err);
                  callback(true, null);
          }
        }); 
    }
});
```

There must be something wrong with this subsequent promises because the  `this.page.property('onResourceRequested'...` function in the penultimate then block is fired like 40 times (one per each url called inside the website after login) but the last `then` is only fired once (when first url is requested).

I want to obtain the data from one concrete url (the one that contains maps.json in the url) which is call number 32.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fire the last then only when my call is done?

---

EDIT:

Following @charlieetfl's advice I canged the code to the following, but still not working...:

```
phantom.create()
.then(function (ph) {
    this.ph = ph;
    return ph.createPage();
})
.then(function (page) {
    this.page = page;
    return page.open('https://example.com');
})
.then(function (status) {

    if ( status === "success" ) {
        return this.page.evaluate(function() {
              document.querySelector("input[name='j_username']").value = 'example@example.net';
              document.querySelector("input[name='j_password']").value = 'example';
              console.log('Submitting logging...');
              document.querySelector("input[name='submit']").click();
        });
   } else {
       return null;
   }
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Logged in!");
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        this.page.property('onResourceRequested', function(requestData, networkRequest) {
            //This event is fired 40 times, only one is interesting to me the one that has the text maps.json in it
            if (requestData.url.indexOf('maps.json') !== -1) {
                resolve({headers: requestData.headers, url: requestData.url});
            }
        });
    });
});
.then(function (data) {
    //This then block is only fired once, with the first call of the first url in previous then block and data is null
    if (data) {
        // This code block is never fired because this then is only called once with data=null
        console.log(data);

        request.get({
                uri: data.url,
                headers: data.headers
        }, function(err, res, body){
          if (!err) {
                callback(null, res.headers);
          } else  {
                  console.log("Error getting data from URL: "+ err);
                  callback(true, null);
          }
        }); 
    }
});
```

---

EDIT: 21/07/2017 10:52 UTC.

I changed the code to this new one:

```
phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
  ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
    page.open('https://example.com/').then(function(status) {
          if ( status === "success" ) {
            page.evaluate(function() {
                  document.querySelector("input[name='j_username']").value = 'example';
                  document.querySelector("input[name='j_password']").value = 'example';
                  console.log('Submitting logging...');
                  document.querySelector("input[name='submit']").click();
            }).then(function(){

                  page.property('onResourceRequested', function(requestData) {
                        if (requestData.url.indexOf('geomaps.json') !== -1) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(datos));
                            request.get({
                                    uri: requestData.url,
                                    headers: requestData.headers
                            }, function(err, res, body){
                                  if (!err) {
                                        console.log(res.headers);
                                  } else  {
                                        console.log("Error getting data from website: "+ err);
                                  }
                            });

                        }
                  });

            });

          }
    });
  });
});
```

Same result. The console.log(JSON.stringify(datos)); is being fired but the request.get is never being fired.

I thing may have something to do with firing async funcions inside promises?

---

EDIT 21/07/2017 11:09 UTC

More tests. If I simplify the page.property('onResourceRequested' code block I see that the then() is called only once and before the requestData is received for each call...

[image]

I am a little bit confused and I don't know right now how to approach this...

Comment: Nothing is being returned in second last `then()`. Return a promise and resolve that promise when you encounter the `maps.json`. Note that return in inner callback does not return to outer function ... in this case the `then()`

Comment: thanks @charlietfl. I don't really understand what I need to do. In second last "then()" do I have to create a new promise like "return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)" and inside it call the "this.page.property('onResourceRequested" function and inside  "if (requestData.url.indexOf('maps.json') !== -1)" call resolve(dataObject)?

Comment: Yes...that is perfect

Comment: @charlietfl thanks again for your help. I edited the OP with the code that you suggested but it is not working. Last then() is now never being fired. There must be something else I am missing...

Comment: Does a new page load after login? Or is it a single page app? Can you log to console inside the `if()` where the resolve is?

Comment: @charlietfl It is a new page

Comment: Add .catch block to the end, there is probably exception.

Comment: @dfsq thanks for your replay! I added a .catch() block after the second last then and another one after the last the() but no error raised :(

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue.
`page.property('onResourceRequested'` executes in the PhantomJS process. PhantomJS does not share any memory or variables with node. So using closures in javascript to share any variables outside of the function is not possible.
using `page.on('onResourceRequested'` instead fixed the issue!